# What is the general everyday term to express the interface between the door and the door frame?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary

Look at the picture

[image]

Children often accidentally put their hands or fingers in the interface between the door and the door frame, which is dangerous because they might get crushed by chance.

**What is the general everyday term to express the interface between the door and the door frame?**

Do you say "**Don't put your fingers in the door gap as they might get crushed**"?

Comment: I don't know of any everyday term for it. I would probably just say _in there_.

Comment: *"Don't get your fingers caught **in the door**."* However, that normally applies to the *other* side of the door. I've never known anybody to specifically refer to the area you are calling out. I don't think any such word exists.